# Lists.asmx returns 404 Page Not Found in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: list, web-services, iis

I am trying to add a web reference. So trying to reach `http://server/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` from my browser. I can see the list services listed down but when I select the Service Description (or `http://server/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL`) I get 404 Page not found. I have tried using admin credentials, using NTLM/Kerberos and enabling Anonymous Authentication. But nothing worked, I am stuck with this for last one week, can't get the web reference added.

Comment: do you have root level site collection in the web app?

Comment: Yes I am trying to access the root level site collection list itself like  -> http://myserver/_vti_bin/lists.asmx. Not http://myserver/sitecollection/mysite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765684/sharepoint-ootb-web-services-asmx-to-wsdl-conversion-not-working

Comment: Thanks but still nothing. I need help in understanding the IIS authentication settings? moreover, I checked the log there is nothing related this error.

Comment: Hi did you ever figure out this issue? I am having the same thing

Comment: @Justin Payne Yeah turns out I needed to have a site at the top level of my site collection, for eg my site was http://servername/sites/mysitename, I needed to have a site at http://servername/. So now that I have that site created, I could add the web service using http://server/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL